# Error building velocity with maven

Tags: java, apache, maven, velocity

I've downloaded the `velocity-1.7.zip` from http://velocity.apache.org/download.cgi  and then, I followed the steps on http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/build.html

but it has reported an error when I typed `mvn build`.

Here is the message:
[image]
How can I fix it? Thank you very much!

Comment: `mvn build` isn't a correct command...

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded the source or just binaries?

It looks like pom.xml file is missing which is needed by maven to run the build. You can download it from http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/velocity/engine/branches/1.7.x/pom.xml